# Change menu based on session value with Angular and Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter, session

I wan't to dynamically display menu items based on session state in codeigniter. Let me show you my code with following explanations.

This is my index.html file

```
                    <li><p ng-bind-html="link1" ></p></li>
                    <li><p ng-bind-html="link2" ></p></li>
```

That link data comes out of this controller

```
sessionFactory.isLoggedIn().then(function(data){
    var loggedIn = data.logged_in;
    if(loggedIn == true){
        $scope.link1 = $sce.trustAsHtml('<a href="#/my_profile">My profile</a>');
        $scope.link2 = $sce.trustAsHtml('<a ng-click="logOut()" style=\"cursor: pointer;" >Logout</a>');
    }else{
        $scope.link1 = $sce.trustAsHtml('<a href="#/login">Login</a>');
        $scope.link2 = $sce.trustAsHtml('<a href="#/register" >Register</a>');
    }
})
```

This is my session factory

```
//Factory for Session
app.factory('sessionFactory', ['$http', '$location', function($http, $location){
    var factory = {};

    factory.logOutUser = function(){
        console.log("woot");
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: $location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host() + '/server/api/users/logout'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log('error logging out: ' + response);
        });
    }

    factory.isLoggedIn = function(){
        console.log("checking login");
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: $location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host() + '/server/api/users/isLoggedIn'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            return response.data;
        },function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log('Checking login failed: ' + response);
        });
    }

    /*
    /server/api/users/logoutfactory.currentUserId = function(){
        return $http.get($location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host() + '/server/api/users/userId');
    }
    */
    return factory;
}]);
```

Api `/server/api/users/isLoggedIn` returns

```
{"success":true,"logged_in":true}
```

or

```
{"success":true,"logged_in":false}
```

So i have the problem that when user logs in or logs out `<li></li>` items don't change. I have to press f5 to refresh web page.
If you need any additional information, please let me know and i will provide.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: instead of inserting html why not have all the links there by default and set a boolean with the session and use angulars built in dirctives for `ng-show` only showing if there is a true value.

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle/plunker?

Comment: @JoeLloyd Yes i change it back, i was thinking that maybe this was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fire an event on the `$rootScope` with

```
$rootScope.$emit("authenticationChanged")
```

on your session factory when the user logs in and out and then in the controller run

```js
function checkIfLogged() {
  var loggedIn = data.logged_in;
  if (loggedIn == true) {
    $scope.link1 = $sce.trustAsHtml('<a href="#/my_profile">My profile</a>');
    $scope.link2 = $sce.trustAsHtml('<a ng-click="logOut()" style=\"cursor: pointer;" >Logout</a>');
  } else {
    $scope.link1 = $sce.trustAsHtml('<a href="#/login">Login</a>');
    $scope.link2 = $sce.trustAsHtml('<a href="#/register" >Register</a>');
  }
}
checkIfLogged(); //RUN THE FIRST TIME THE PAGE LOADS

$rootScope.$on("authenticationChanged", function(){
    checkIfLogged(); //RUN WHEN AUTHENTICATION CHANGE
});
```

For more informations about events check https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Comment: Don't use `$rootScope` for this type of thing. global variables have a time and a place but this is not one of those times.

Comment: It's not a global variable. It's a global event.. It need to fire all across the application from the service to the controller

Comment: I tried but it didn't help. Probably because i'm to noobish to understand the code. I will keep on trying

Comment: Do you have errors ? Logs ? Can you show something ? Glad to help

Comment: Perhaps you could post the code, so I can take a look ? If you want of course

Comment: Sorry guys i have some lover back problem. I will re try everything when i will be better..

Answer (score 1):

You can try using functions for getting the link contents:

```
<li><p ng-bind-html="getLink1Content(false)"></p></li>
<li><p ng-bind-html="getLink2Content(false)"></p></li>

$scope.getLink1Content = function (loggedIn) {
    var linkContent = loggedIn ? '<a href="#/my_profile">My profile</a>' : '<a href="#/login">Login</a>';

    return linkContent;
};

$scope.getLink2Content = function (loggedIn) {
    var linkContent = loggedIn '<a ng-click="logOut()" style=\"cursor: pointer;" >Logout</a>' : '<a href="#/register" >Register</a>';

    return linkContent;
}

sessionFactory.isLoggedIn().then(function(data){
    var loggedIn = data.logged_in;

    $scope.getLink1Content(loggedIn);
    $scope.getLink2Content(loggedIn);
});
```

Comment: Sorry guys i have some lover back problem. I will re try everything when i will be better..